# JavaScript regex - hyphens between numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to find a regex to replace all hyphens between numbers for javascript `replace()`

**String:**

```
-14-2
```

**RegEx:**

```
/(?<=\d)-(?=\d)/
```

This works well for PHP and Ruby, but it doesn't appear that JavaScript supports look behind.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you replacing the hyphens with?

Comment: Wow, some edit :) How about the regular expression you originally posted?

Comment: Whoops!  I just updated the post.  I am replacing it with a decimal so it can be parsed into a float `var prevVal = parseFloat(quoteObj.text().replace(/(?<=\d)-(?=\d)/, "."));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "-14-2";
var re = /(\d)-(\d)/;
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$1.$2");
console.log(newstr)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/suht59rt/)**

Comment: Thanks!  Chalk one up for simplicity!

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = '-14-2-'
var r = s.replace(/(\d)?-(?=\d)/g, function($0, $1) {
      return $1 ? $1+'.' : $0
}); //=> "-14.2-"
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds unfortunately.

In your case, you could use something like this:

```
var numbers = "-14-2";
numbers.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)/, "$1.$2")
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there more to the string than you've showed? Because you can simply do

```
var f = "-14-2"; 
f.replace(/(\d)-(\d)/,function(a,b,c){
    return b+"."+c}
);
//.14.2
```

Comment: "replace all hyphens between numbers". This replaces all of them.

Comment: @j08691 Unless they edited the answer, it doesn't even do **that**